# Virtualbox NAT 22 to 22 fail (HOST port 22 has no program listening)

Tags: ssh, nat, virtualbox

I am using virtualbox 4.1.16 on a Ubuntu 12.04 x64 vm host and all NAT is working properly, like HOST 2222 -> Client 22

But I have changed my HOST `sshd` to listen on port 81 and restarted, so host port 22 is free. and order my guest vm to do a NAT (HOST)22 to (CLIENT)22. while the same vm guest, if I map NAT 1234 to 22, it works again.

I have tried `ufw disable`, `/etc/init.d/apparmor stop`, nothing helps

Is there anything I need to do to make it happen?

Comment: promblem remains but I have found a workaround by port forwarding using iptables `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p TCP --dport 22 -j REDIRECT --to-port 1234`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like your VirtualBox process is not running with the right privileges allow it to bind to ports below 1024 - typically that requires root level permissions. According to the VirtualBox manual, there are four limitations to the NAT engine:

- ICMP protocol limitations, ping works but a lot of things may have trouble
- Receiving of UDP broadcasts is not reliable
- Protocols such as GRE are unsupported
- **Forwarding host ports < 1024 impossible** on Unix hosts like Linux, Solaris, Mac OS X without running as root.

Reference: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#nat-limitations

The best workaround would be to configure your virtual machine to use a bridged virtual network adapter if that will work in your environment.